# how to write using alias name using kafka connect to elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am having Kafka connect to read from a topic and write it into elastic search.

I get an alias name in the key of record which I am extracting with smt.
elastic search cluster has all index and alias and mapping created before ingesting any data.

how should i use the extracted alias name from connect and how can I redirect into exact indices with the alias name through Kafka-connect.

can it be done via custom smt? if so how?